# Closed form for $\Gamma(n+\frac{2}{3})$

Tags: number-theory, factorial, gamma-function, constants

I'm looking for a good closed form for $\Gamma(n+\frac{2}{3})$ involving at most $\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})$.

I know that $\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{3})=\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})\frac{(3n-2)!!!}{3^n}$ and my question is, is there an analogous for $\Gamma(n+\frac{2}{3})$?

I tried using WolframAlpha and ended up finding out that:

$$
\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}
$$
$$
\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)=\frac{4\pi}{3\sqrt{3}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}
$$
$$
\Gamma\left(\frac{8}{3}\right)=\frac{20\pi}{9\sqrt{3}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}
$$
$$...$$
and noticed the possible pattern:
$$
\Gamma\left(n+\frac{2}{3}\right)=\frac{2t_n\pi}{3^n\sqrt{3}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}
$$
where $t_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(3k+2\right)$ is [OEIS A008544](https://oeis.org/A008544).

Is this true? How can we prove it?

Comment: Use $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$, also $\Gamma(\theta)\Gamma(1-\theta)=\pi/\sin(\pi\theta)$ for $\theta\in(0,1)$.

Comment: @Feng oh okay, simpler than I thought. Thank you!

Comment: @FrankSoll It is allowed to answer your own question if you found a nice closed-form with a proof, so it will no longer be in the unanswered list.